# Error on "apidoc" lib while run on Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, api-doc

I am getting error on apidoc (apidoc-0.50.3 version) while run in Docker and  I am using Node `v12.22.7`

Command :

```
RUN npm install apidoc -g
RUN apidoc -e node_modules
```

Error :

```
node_modules/apidoc/lib/writer.js:136
const title = projectInfo.title ?? projectInfo.name ?? 'Loading...';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

Help me to find out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer : https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc/issues/1045
.Needed to upgrade nodejs